# how can i play rtsp video stream in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, rtsp, flutter-video-player

**this is my  code thats i m trying by using `flutter vlc player` but its not working so any can help me to solving the issue or i can show stream with another way?**

so you guys can give me any suggestion or give any little example. i m trying to solve this issue from last two hours but its not going

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/vlc_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/vlc_player_controller.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  VlcPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _videoPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.network(
      'rtsp://viewer:aeDoPhiucees3gohshie@173.249.14.110:27954/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&fps=15&audio=1&resolution=640x480',
      hwAcc: HwAcc.FULL,
      autoPlay: false,
      options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    await _videoPlayerController.stopRendererScanning();
    await _videoPlayerController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: VlcPlayer(
          controller: _videoPlayerController,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a small example that works for me. I think the problem is that in the newer versions the Controller must be initialized immediately.

The only problems I have with this code is that the advanced options take no effect. Unfortunately it is hard to find some good information

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/src/vlc_player_controller.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  VlcPlayerController _vlcViewController = new VlcPlayerController.network(
    "rtsp://192.72.1.1/liveRTSP/av4",
    autoPlay: true,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new VlcPlayer(
              controller: _vlcViewController,
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              placeholder: Text("Hello World"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip about initializing the controller immediately.  That solved my problem!

Comment: Are there any license issues involved with the use of VLC. VLC is a phenomenal library, but isn't it GPL?

Comment: flutter_vlc_player is not available for Windows & Linux :(

Answer (score 5):

Developer of [package:media_kit](https://github.com/media-kit/media-kit) here.

It can play RTSP, RTMP, HLS, DASH on all platforms (Android, iOS, macOS, Windows & GNU/Linux) with hardware acceleration.

Install: https://github.com/media-kit/media-kit#installation

It's very easy to use:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:media_kit/media_kit.dart';                      // Provides [Player], [Media], [Playlist] etc.
import 'package:media_kit_video/media_kit_video.dart';          // Provides [VideoController] & [Video] etc.        

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Necessary initialization for package:media_kit.
  MediaKit.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyScreen(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyScreen> createState() => MyScreenState();
}

class MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  // Create a [Player] to control playback.
  late final player = Player();
  // Create a [VideoController] to handle video output from [Player].
  late final controller = VideoController(player);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Play a [Media] or [Playlist].
    player.open(Media('https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28951144/229373695-22f88f13-d18f-4288-9bf1-c3e078d83722.mp4'));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 9.0 / 16.0,
        // Use [Video] widget to display video output.
        child: Video(controller: controller),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this lib: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_playout. It does support HLS.